# python tkinter how to bind key to a button

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library

New to programming and especially python and tKinter. How can I create a way to bind the key "s" to the button or the function `sharpen`? Any help would be awesome.

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter, ImageEnhance

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.wm_title("Image examples")
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

def createWidgets(self):
    self.img = Image.open("lineage.jpg")
    self.photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img.convert("RGB"))
    self.label1 = Label(self, image=self.photo1)
    self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)

    self.photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img.convert("RGB"))
    self.label2 = Label(self, image=self.photo2)
    self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)

    button5 = Button(self, text="Sharpen", command=self.sharpen)
    button5.grid(row=4, column= 2, sticky = N)

def sharpen(self):
    img2 = self.img.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
    self.photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
    self.label2 = Label(self, image=self.photo2)
    self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll need to make two changes:

1. Add

   ```
   master.bind('s', self.sharpen)
   ```

   to `__init__`. (Binding to the Frame, `self`, does not seem to work.)
2. When <kbd>s</kbd> is pressed, `self.sharpen(event)` will be called. Since
   Tkinter will be sending a `Tkinter.Event` object, we must also change the call
   signature to

   ```
   def sharpen(self, event=None):
   ```

   Thus, when the button is pressed, `event` will be set to the default
   value, `None`, but when the <kbd>s</kbd> key is pressed, `event` 
   will be assigned to the `Tkinter.Event` object.

Comment: Will it take for account whether the button is disabled or not. I think it should rather be binded with Button.invoke().

Answer (score 2):

Use `bind_all` like this:

```
def sharpen(self, event):
    master.bind_all('s', sharpen)
```

You can find more info at the [Python docs](https://www.python.org/doc/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind`. I'm going to assume the indenting in your question is wrong and `sharpen` is an `Application` method.

```
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.wm_title("Image examples")
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
        self.bind("s", self.sharpen)
```

[Pythonware](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/events-and-bindings.htm) has useful information about event handling.