# Which keys can be in the binding key field?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been working on a code for the "4 in a row" game, and I've a lot of things settled so far.

I googled it but I really couldn't find any options for which keys can be in the binding key field.

```
board_canvas.bind("<Key>", some_random_callback_hihi)
```

My question, to be more clear is if I can replace "" with any kind of other specific key. For example, how would you bind with the key `"<2>"`?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) page,

> There are also various ways to simplify the event string; for example, to match a keyboard key, you can leave out the angle brackets and just use the key as is.

... so to bind the "A" key, you would do

```
board_canvas.bind("a", some_random_callback_hihi)
```

And to bind the "2" key, you would do

```
board_canvas.bind("2", some_random_callback_hihi)
```

Etc.

Note: the canvas doesn't get keyboard focus by default. You will need to arrange for it to have focus. For more information see [Python Tkinter Canvas fail to bind keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269682/python-tkinter-canvas-fail-to-bind-keyboard) .