# keyboard binding in piano python

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard

how can I bind keyboard in piano using python GUI?

I tried using bind but I did not know how to use that.

```
btnCs = Button(ABC2,  height = 6, width = 6, bd = 4, text = "C#", font =('arial', 18 , 'bold'), bg = "black",  fg = "white", command = value_Cs)
```

I expect an example using the code given help me pls

Comment: Are you using tkinter?

Comment: yes, I do. do I need to send the whole code? help me pls

Comment: No, but the snippet where you try to bind might help, what is your error? Maybe that's not needed either, I think this could be a duplicate of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326940/python-tkinter-how-to-bind-key-to-a-button)

Comment: I want to use my keyboard instead of the button in GUI and I tried 
btnCs.bind("a", value_Cs) and it is not working.

Comment: Try binding the key to the root window, not to the button widget.

Comment: can you give an example of how to do it?

Comment: Yes just did it, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch the console output running your function when you press the `a` key in your keyboard. You need to focus the tkinter window with the mouse. `event=None` is needed because the binded callback function gets passed an event object by the tkinter event loop (mainloop):

```
from tkinter import Tk

def play_a(event=None):
    print('Play the A key sound')

root = Tk()
root.bind('a', play_a)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are welcome @Noel, see also [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) about events and binding in tkinter.